# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect() is a string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, dotenv

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDatabase = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  console.log("MongoDB Connection Successfully");
};

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

My `config.env` file

```
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.aq9vco8.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Before you call the `connectDatabase` function do a `console.log('uri=', process.env.MONGO_URI)` to make sure your environment variables have loaded. I suspect not which means you will need to share more code to establish why.

Comment: add a if condition to check the env exists mongo_uri value or not before making the connection to db

Comment: @jQueeny console.log('uri=', process.env.MONGO_URI) is showing undefined

Comment: You will need to post your app.js or index.js or whatever your main file is called so that I can see how you are importing the `dotenv` module. Is your `.env` file in the root directory or in a subdirectory?